# Shipping motorcycles from Russia to USA

Tags: usa, canada, russia, shipping, motorcycles

A friend and I are thinking of doing a motorcycle trip around the world (Long Way Round). I know the airport in Magadan is now closed.

Does anyone know of an airline which would ship two motorbikes from the East coast of Russia to a city in either Canada or the United States?

Comment: If you dont get an answer, I remember seeing some travelogue movie where a couple of bikers drive through the world on their Royal Enfield motor cycles. May be that movie has some clues.

Comment: @happybuddha maybe it has a title ...

Comment: @hunter2 I dont remember now. May be it was part of a show on one of the TV channels.

Comment: @Lt_Shade If you haven't googled yet, may be this article provides some help : http://askyakutia.com/2012/09/how-to-ship-vehicles-from-magadan-russia-to-anchorage-alaskausa/

Comment: Thanks @happybuddha some useful tips in there. I have found a few sites saying the best thing to do is to ship the Bikes to South Korea and then to Vancouver

Comment: @Lt_Shade Do you care which direction it goes?

Comment: I would prefer to go from Asia towards the States but would also consider the reverse if a solution was found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend that you start with contacting the [airport in Magadan](http://www.airport-magadan.ru/en/raspis/main.html) to see if they have Cargo carriers landing there and which ones they are.  Then contact them directly.  No information is available online on the airport site.

Given that you're in Russia I would recommend contacting [Aeroflot Cargo Services](http://www.aeroflot.com/cms/cargo_transport) as they are the largest and likely to have cargo flights from Magadan.  They are likely, however, to carry your bikes "in the wrong direction" to Anchorage.